# Header setup for all tables to fit page width

Tags: tables

I would like to know if there is package and command that I could include in my LaTeX article header that makes all tables fit to page width.

Something similar to the floatrow package and the floatsetup command.

For example:

```
\usepackage{floatrow}

\floatsetup[table]{style=plaintop}
```

Comment: The only way to force tabulars to fit the page is to use `\resizebox` (adjustbox package), but we (generally speaking) do not recommend this approach.  Fitting tables to the page should be done on a case by case basis with much thought.

Comment: It is not clear what you like to achieve. Bad looking article? Bad looking tables? For tables which  widths is equal to `\textwidth` you can use `\begin{tabular*}{linewidth}{ ... }` or `tabularx` tables.

Comment: What if one table has a natural width of, say `0.2/textwidth` and another of `2\textwidth`?

Comment: forcing ables to full width just forces the columns to be furher apart so making the table harder to read, you can of course simply use `{tabular*}{\texwidth}`  instead of `{tabular}`, but why?